# Creating signed URL in Cloudfront is slower than S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

[image]

After I switched creating signed URL for files in S3 to files in Cloudfront, the latency increased significantly. The above figure shows the difference.

I think cloudfront is using RSA, but not sure the algorithm behind S3 signed url.

Any idea why it happened? Thanks in advance.